# Retrieving count from nested select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query, which works exactly as intended (thanks to the helpful people at stackoverflow). However, I realized that in addition to using the count to validate whether messages is <= 3 I also want to retrieve the actual number/count for each row that is returned in the results.

This is so that I can customize the logic depending on how many messages each of the returned users has.

I have tried a few different options but it's not quite working.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE 
 NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM events e 
    WHERE e.user_id = u.id AND e.type = 'collection'
 )
 AND (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM messages m 
    WHERE m.user_id = u.id AND m.message_type = 'collection_reminder'
 ) <= 3
AND u.admin IS NULL
```

Comment: If you use the second part of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55582191/4104224) to the original question, you can just include the count in the select list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move that subquery to the select list. Put the condition in a `having` clause at the end (MySQL special trick).

```
SELECT u.*,
       (
          SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM messages m 
          WHERE m.user_id = u.id AND m.message_type = 'collection_reminder'
      ) as cnt
FROM users u
WHERE 
 NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM events e 
    WHERE e.user_id = u.id AND e.type = 'collection'
 )
AND u.admin IS NULL
HAVING cnt <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification of my answer from the original question:

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(DISTINCT m.message_id)
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN events AS e ON u.user_id = e.user_id AND e.event_type = 'Collection'
LEFT JOIN messages AS m ON u.user_id = m.user_id AND m.msg_type = 'Collection Reminder'
WHERE u.admin = 0
   AND e.event_id IS NULL        -- No event of type collection
GROUP BY u.user_id -- Note: you should group on all selected fields, and 
                   -- some configuration of MySQL will require you do so.
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT m.message_id) < 3   -- Less than 3 collection reminder messages 
             -- distinct is optional, but 
             -- if you were to remove the "no event" condition, 
             -- multiple events could multiply the message count.
;
```